# Can't see my texture on 2d object using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, textures

I'm trying to use textures in my mini OpenGL program. As using OpenGL requires a lot of duplicated code so I abstracted my code into a class. But I can't see anything on the window. OpenGL doesn't throw any errors. I'm using [`stb_image.h`](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) from https://github.com/nothings/stb/ to process image files. What I am doing wrong? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Class declaration:

```cpp
class texture {
protected:
    unsigned int textureid;
    unsigned char* localbuf;
    int length, width, pixelbit;
    std::string srcpath;
public:
    texture(std::string file);
    ~texture();
    int getwidth() const;
    int getlength() const;
    void bind(unsigned int slot = 0) const;
    void unbind() const;
};
```

Class implementation:

```cpp
texture::texture(std::string file) {
    srcpath = file;

    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    localbuf = stbi_load(file.c_str(), &width, &length, &pixelbit, 4);

    glcall(glGenTextures(1, &textureid));
    glcall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureid));

    glcall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    glcall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    glcall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    glcall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));

    glcall(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, length, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, localbuf))

    glcall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));

    if (localbuf) stbi_image_free(localbuf);
}

texture::~texture() {
    glcall(glDeleteTextures(1, &textureid));
}

void texture::bind(unsigned int slot) const {
    glcall(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + slot));
    glcall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureid));
}

void texture::unbind() const {
    glcall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
}

int texture::getwidth() const {
    return width;
}

int texture::getlength() const {
    return length;
}
```

Vertex shader:

```c
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texpos;
out vec2 v_texpos;
void main() {
    gl_Position = position;
    v_texpos = texpos;
};
```

Fragment shader:

```c
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
in vec2 v_texpos; 
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
void main() {
    vec4 texcolor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texpos);
    color = texcolor;
};
```

`main` function:

```cpp
int main() {
    ...
    texture mytexture("path/to/image/file.png");
    texture.bind();
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "u_texture"), 0);
    ...
    while (window_open) {
        ...
        glDrawElements(...);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: For debug reasons only: Do you "see" something when you do `color = texcolor + 0.5;`

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, I can see a light yellow color.

Comment: There is no obvious mistake in this code.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Do you want to say that issue is in `stb_image.h` or the image file?

Comment: Most likely the bug is not in `stb_image.h`. Possibly the image path is not correct (try an absolute path). Anyway I don't know what exactly happens in your main program. Is this a snippet from the actual code?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, It is a snippet from actual code. I have tried to use an absolute path but no effects.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Should I upload the whole source code somewhere and give a link here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using class to handle the layout of vertices. In the implementation of that class, there is a loop like this:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < ...; i++) {
    ...
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(i);
    ...
}
```

Above one is correct, but I made a mistake previously by typing `0` instead of `i` like this:

```cpp
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

When I was not dealing with textures, this loop was run once and the value of `i` was `0` . But when started to deal with textures, this loop was run twice and `i` wasn't always `0` , resulting in an error.